# How to get one row per unique ID with multiple columns per values of particular column

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr, spread, dcast

I have a dataset that looks like (A) and I'm trying to get (B):

```
#(A)
event <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D')
person <- c('Ann', 'Sally', 'Ryan', 'Ann', 'Ryan', 'Sally', 'Ann', 'Sally', 'Ryan')
birthday <- c('1990-10-10', NA, NA, NA, '1985-01-01', NA, '1990-10-10', '1950-04-02', NA)
data <- data.frame(event, person, birthday)

#(B)
person <- c('Ann', 'Sally', 'Ryan')
A <- c(1, 1, 1)
B <- c(1, 0, 1)
C <- c(0, 0, 1)
D <- c(1, 1, 1)
birthday <- c('1990-10-10', '1950-04-02', '1985-01-01')
data <- data.frame(person, A, B, C, D, birthday)
```

Basically, I have a sign-up list of events and can see people who attended various ones. I want to get a list of all the unique people with columns for which events they did/didn't attend. I also got profile data from some of the events, but some had more data than others - so I also want to keep the most filled out data (i.e. couldn't identify Ryan's birthday from event D but could from event B).

I've tried looking up many different things but get confused between whether I should be looking at reshaping, vs. dcast, vs. spread/gather... new to R so any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Additional q - instead of indicating 1/0 for if someone went an event, if multiple events were in the same category, how would you identify how many times someone went to that category of event? E.g., I would have events called A1, A2, and A3 in the dataset as well. The final table would still have a column called A, but instead of just 1/0, it would say 0 if the person attended no A events, and 1, 2, or 3 if the person attended 1, 2, or 3 A events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should isolate birthdays which is not represented cleanly in your table ; then you should reshape and finally get birthdays back.

Using the package `reshape2` :

```
birthdays <- unique(data[!is.na(data$birthday),c("person","birthday")])
reshaped <- reshape2::dcast(data,person ~ event, value.var = "event",fun.aggregate = length)
final <- merge(reshaped,birthdays)
```

Explications : I just told reshape2::dcast to put my `person` into rows and `event` into columns, and count every occurrence (made by the aggregation function `length`) of event.

EDIT: for your additional question, it works just the same, just add substr() on the event variable :

```
   reshaped <- reshape2::dcast(data,person ~ substr(event,1,1), value.var = "event",fun.aggregate = length)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this! Is there a quick way to isolate and remerge the "other info"? I.e. I only included birthday for this sample, but I actually collected a lot of profile data, so the data set is actually much larger (e.g., has event, name, birthday, name, phone, etc...)

Comment: If you don't want to isolate this data first, with this method you will have to "fill the blanks". In other terms, you will need to replace the NAs with appropriate values ; then, you could just add birthday to the rows :

   reshaped <- reshape2::dcast(data,person + birthday~ substr(event,1,1) , value.var = "event",fun.aggregate = length)

Answer (score 3):

A `data.table` option

```
dcast(
  setDT(data),
  person + na.omit(birthday)[match(person, person[!is.na(birthday)])] ~ event,
  fun = length
)
```

gives

```
   person   birthday A B C D
1:    Ann 1990-10-10 1 1 0 1
2:   Ryan 1985-01-01 1 1 0 1
3:  Sally 1950-04-02 1 0 1 1
```

---

A base R option using `reshape`

```
reshape(
  transform(
    data,
    birthday = na.omit(birthday)[match(person, person[!is.na(birthday)])],
    cnt = 1
  ),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = c("person", "birthday"),
  timevar = "event"
)
```

gives

```
  person   birthday cnt.A cnt.B cnt.C cnt.D
1    Ann 1990-10-10     1     1    NA     1
2  Sally 1950-04-02     1    NA     1     1
3   Ryan 1985-01-01     1     1    NA     1
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Works as well, accepted Leon's answer since he posted first, but appreciate it